# Date and Time from string to php time

Tags: php, date, time

Hi Im trying to get the string    "25.01.2017 08:22:10" to a valid php time

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, 25.01.2017 08:22:10);
```

does not work. Maybe its because of the dots...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd.m.Y H:i:s', 
    '25.01.2017 08:22:10'
);
```

**Note** Adjusted the date format and surrounded the date with `'` (it needs to be a `string`).

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php